# Include method under urls.py not working: Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, pycharm

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from pages import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('dashboard/', include(pages.urls)),
]
```

I'm trying to use include method under my urls.py file to direct the dashboad/ request to my app urls.py file, which is not working.

[image: As shown in image the when I'm trying to import views from pages it gives me error saying no module pages]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change this line :

```
path('dashboard/', include(pages.urls)),
```

to this :

```
path('dashboard/', include('pages.urls')),
```

see this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#re-path)

Comment: Thank you for the help this solved my problem, the code executed normally, but it still showing red line below the pages even after restarting the pyCharm

Comment: No, the trail version (i accidentally downloaded the trail version instead of community), is that the reason of the problem?

Comment: do you registered your app in `INSTALLED_APP` in `settings.py`?

Comment: Uninstalling Trail version & Reinstalling PyCharm Community version solved the problem, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow!

The problem you are facing is that Django expects the `include(...)` method to be given a list of url patterns or the string of the module url's you want to be included at the path.

I would refactor your code like so:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from pages import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('dashboard/', include('pages.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help this solved my problem, the code executed normally, but it still showing red line below the pages even after restarting the pyCharm

Comment: @ZohaibShamshad could you provide a screenshot or copy and paste the error you're seeing?